# How do get the Linked_Account_Name while calling the cost explorer API

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have the below code to get the cost explorer details using boto3 which will give the data on the basis of account_id.I need the details on the basis of Linked_account_Name. Can someone guide me how to proceed..

```
response = ce.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
    'Start': '2020-01-01',
    'End': '2020-01-03'
    },
Granularity='MONTHLY',
Metrics=[
    'UnblendedCost',
],
GroupBy=[
    {
        'Type': 'DIMENSION',
        'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT'
    },
]
```

Comment: I have tried to pass linked_account_name while doing group by, but group by will take only the below values: 
 Valid values are AZ, INSTANCE_TYPE, LINKED_ACCOUNT, OPERATION, PURCHASE_TYPE, SERVICE, USAGE_TYPE, PLATFORM, TENANCY, RECORD_TYPE, LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME, DEPLOYMENT_OPTION, DATABASE_ENGINE, CACHE_ENGINE, INSTANCE_TYPE_FAMILY, REGION, BILLING_ENTITY, RESERVATION_ID, SAVINGS_PLANS_TYPE, SAVINGS_PLAN_ARN, OPERATING_SYSTEM",

Answer (score 0):

LINKED_ACCOUNT_NAME is not valid for all three context(COST_AND_USAGE','RESERVATIONS','SAVINGS_PLANS).

**Dimensions are also limited to LINKED_ACCOUNT , REGION , or RIGHTSIZING_TYPE in get_cost_and_usage()**
So, you won't be able to use it.

You can use

> get_dimension_values()
> [use this link for more info](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_dimension_values)

function to get the Linked Account name.

```
client = session.client('ce')
response = client.get_dimension_values(
SearchString='123456789098',
TimePeriod={
    'Start': '2020-01-01',
    'End': '2020-03-01'
},
Dimension='LINKED_ACCOUNT',
Context='COST_AND_USAGE'
)
for each in response['DimensionValues']:
    print('Account Name is ->', each['Attributes']['description'])
```

and output will be like below:

```
Account Name is -> Test 0100
```

Its not a complete answer but  you can proceed from here.